# "Cold" start of S3, DynamoDB, KMS or whatever

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I use NodeJs AWS Lambdas. If I don't do calls to my S3, or DynamoDB, or KMS for some time (approx. 8h or more) the first call I make is usually painfully slow - up-to 5sec. There's nothing complex in the queries themselves - i.e. get a 0.2Kb S3 object, query a DynamoDB table by index.

So, it looks like AWS "hibernates" these resources when they aren't in active use and when I call them for the 1st time after a while they spend some time to return from "hibernated" state. This is my assumption, but I couldn't find any information about it in docs. So, the questions are the following two:

1. Is my assumption about "hibernation" correct?
2. If 1st point is correct, then is there any way to mitigate these "cold" calls to AWS services except keeping those services "warm" by calling them every X minutes?

**Edit**

Just to avoid confusions - this is not about Lambda's cold starts. I'm aware of them, they exist, they have their own share in functions' latency. Times I measure are the exact times of calls to S3/DynamoDB etc. - after the lambda is started.

Comment: I am experiencing the same, and it is not lambda cold starts. Not sure what the remedy is

Comment: Same issue here. We logged a call to SSM and Dynamo to take a combined 2 seconds on the first lambda invocation. These calls are done in a lambda layer, though I doubt that's the cause of this.

Answer (score 3):

We have experienced the same issue for calls to SSM and DynamoDB. It's probably not these services that go into hibernation, but the parameters for calling them are cached on the lambda container, which means they need to be recreated when a new container is spawned.

Unfortunately, we have not found a solution other than pinging the lambda from time to time. In this case, you should execute a call to your services in the ping in order to see an improvement in the loading times. See also below benchmark.

[image: Benchmark of first-call loading times]

Answer (score 2):

It all likelihood it is the lambda function that is hibernating, not the other services:

> A cold start occurs when an AWS Lambda function is invoked after not
>   being used for an extended period of time resulting in increased
>   invocation latency.

https://medium.com/@lakshmanLD/resolving-cold-start%EF%B8%8F-in-aws-lambda-804512ca9b61

and yes, you could setup a cloudwatch event to keep your lambda function warm.

Comment: I see your point. Sorry, I didn't mentioned it in the question - I'm aware of Lambda cold starts. It is not a lambda's cold start, because I measure response times from S3/DynamoDB etc, not the overall Lambda execution time. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 0):

AWS (zoewangg) acknowledged the slow startup issue in 1.11.x Java SDK[1](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1340#issuecomment-606770863).

> One of the main reasons is that 1.11.x SDK uses ApacheHttpClient under
> the hood and initializing it can be expensive.

Check out https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/tuning-the-aws-java-sdk-2-x-to-reduce-startup-time/